# How can I save the user data I got using authservice with firebase in Flutter to firebase?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart, mobile

I have an ordering application. after user create account i can see name and address in firebase table. How can I save the user's name and address in firebase after clicking the place order button? Or is there another way to receive the order?

```
TextButton kayitButon(BuildContext context) {
return TextButton(
  onPressed: () async {
    AuthService().registerUser(kadi: nameController.text, sifre: sifreController.text, adres: adresController.text);
    userData = {
      "name": nameController.text,
      "sifre": sifreController.text,
      "adres": adresController.text
    };
    await kullaniciRef.doc(nameController.text).set(userData);
    if (formkey.currentState!.validate()) {
      formkey.currentState!.save();
      try {
        await fireBaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: kadi,
          password: sifre,
        );
        formkey.currentState!.reset();
        ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(
          SnackBar(
            content: Text("Kayıt İşlemi Başarılı"),
          ),
        );

        Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, "/loginpage");
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
      }
    }
  },
  child: Container(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16),
      color: const Color.fromARGB(255, 83, 188, 83),
    ),
    child: const Text(
      "Kayıt Ol",
      style: TextStyle(
        color: Colors.white,
        // fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        fontSize: 20,
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

}

Comment: when you click the place order you can update the firebase document with the user name and address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> 1.Ensure that the user is logged in before they can place an order. You can do this by implementing a login system using Firebase Authentication or any other authentication mechanism. Make sure to handle user authentication and obtain the necessary user information (username, address) when the user logs in.

> 2.Once the user is logged in, you should have access to their username and address. You can use this information to pass it to the placeOrder function you provided.

> 3.Before calling the placeOrder function, gather the information about the products the user added to the cart. You may have this information stored in your app's state or a separate data structure.

> 4.After collecting all the required information (username, address, and cart products), you can call the placeOrder function with the appropriate data.

```
        // Function to place an order
    void placeOrder(String name, String address, List<Product> 
    cartProducts) 
    {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('orders').add({
        'name': name,
        'address': address,
        'products': cartProducts.map((product) => 
      product.toMap()).toList(),
      }).then((value) {
      // Order saved successfully
         print('Order placed successfully!');
      }).catchError((error) {
        // Error occurred while saving the order
        print('Error placing order: $error');
      });
    }

    // Example of a Product class
    class Product {
      final String name;
      final double price;

      Product(this.name, this.price);

      Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
        return {
          'name': name,
          'price': price,
          // Add other product details as needed
         };
      }
    }

    // Example usage
    void onOrderButtonPressed(User currentUser, List<Product> 
    cartProducts) {
     String username = currentUser.displayName; 

    // Replace with  the appropriate way to get the user's username
      String address = currentUser.address; 

     // Replace with the appropriate way to get the user's address

      placeOrder(username, address, cartProducts);
   }
```

> Please note that the code above assumes you have a class Product to represent the products in the cart, and a User class representing the logged-in user with their display name and address. You will need to adjust the code to fit the structure of your app and authentication system.

> Remember to replace User currentUser with the appropriate way of accessing the current user information from your authentication system. Also, ensure that the Product class includes all the necessary product details you want to save in the Firestore order document.